# OpenCV VS2013 module machine conflics with target machine

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to run simplest OpenCV 2.4.9 program on Visual Studio 2013.
While trying debug i get 
***error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'X64'***.

Keeping to struggle with this for the whole day now, can anyone help me please?

My system is **64bit.**

VisualStudio as always is **32bit.**

I linked:

opencv_249\build\x64\vc12\bin, opencv_249\build\x64\vc12\lib

I set target machine:  **MachineX64 (/MACHINE:X64)**

My active Platform: **x64** (changed from Win32)

EDIT

Even when first setting x64 platform and then linking x64 I get this message, where does x86 come from?:

```
'xxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'xxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'xxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'xxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'B:\Libraries\opencv_249\build\x86\vc12  \bin\opencv_core249d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'xxx.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'B:\Libraries\opencv_249\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_core249d.dll'
The program '[2780] xxx.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

Found this post and seems the problem applies to me since I use Windows8.1,however I did not manage to solve the problem using hints from the post. Has anyone an idea?
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/32-bit-application-fails-to-start-after-81-upgrade/b825723e-e2a2-4c8f-bd1f-10446a5d7059?page=5&tm=1416787803471

XML of .vxproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Filter Include="Source Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{4FC737F1-C7A5-4376-A066-2A32D752A2FF}</UniqueIdentifier>
      <Extensions>cpp;c;cc;cxx;def;odl;idl;hpj;bat;asm;asmx</Extensions>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="Header Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{93995380-89BD-4b04-88EB-625FBE52EBFB}</UniqueIdentifier>
      <Extensions>h;hh;hpp;hxx;hm;inl;inc;xsd</Extensions>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="Resource Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{67DA6AB6-F800-4c08-8B7A-83BB121AAD01}</UniqueIdentifier>
      <Extensions>rc;ico;cur;bmp;dlg;rc2;rct;bin;rgs;gif;jpg;jpeg;jpe;resx;tiff;tif;png;wav;mfcribbon-ms</Extensions>
    </Filter>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="main.cpp">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Did you link and THEN change the project type, and/or created a new target type?  Or what?  Link targets are architecture-specific, so if you did things the in the wrong order, it's possible your link change isn't there.  Posting the contents of your .vcxproj file would help, not just what you've done please.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I first linked then created a new target type. Can you please tell me what exactly do I need to provide from .vcxproj ? Copy the xml content? There i see no info about the version. Eventually, what to do now, delete whole project and create new one?

Comment: Yes copy the XML content itself.  The whole thing.  If it's a small project, then the problems should present themselves and not be too hard to tell where your problem is.  Making a brand-new project and making an x64 project type right away and THEN customizing the x64 one is also an option if you want to try your way through yourself.

Comment: @KevinAnderson thanks, just uploaded, please have a look.. I tried a brand-new project as you mentioned.. result of this I aswell put in EDIT in my post. Somewhere still x86 is linked although I dont know where.

Comment: You gave me the "projectname.vcxproj.filters" file.  I need the one that doesn't have ".filters" at the end.